# Extract values from specific row, column using bash

Tags: bash, sed, awk, extract

I have a sample log file with fields and values in this format

```
value1 value2
 50    100

value3 value4 
 10      150   

value5
 200
```

I need to extract fields and values to something of this format

```
value1=50
value2=100
value3=10
value4=150
value5=200
```

Comment: When you have requirements like these, it's better to switch to a scripting language, like python, ruby, (may god be with you) or even perl.

Comment: Besides... what have you tried?

Comment: Is their something consistent that can be used to key on about the "value" names? I'm tempted to use "value", but if the actual names have nothing in common, it might be difficult to distinguish what is what.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson: Yes the fields have quite different names. I mentioned "values" to make it simple.

Comment: That actually makes it more difficult. Is there anything that reliably distinguishes the name lines? Are there other lines in the file besides names and values? Do the names include any digits?

Comment: I was trying this:                                                  test.awk                                                            BEGIN{RS="\n\n";FS="\t";}{print $1,$2;}                                   awk -f test.awk test.dat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this awk:

```
gawk '{split($0,n_arr," "); getline; n=split($0,v_arr," "); getline; for (i=1;i<=n;i++){print n_arr[i] "=" v_arr[i]}}'
```

Comment: I was trying to tweak the output dealing with the format. I intend to put the extracted values in a single line delimited by a comma making sure that there are no non-numeric values in it. I was implementing this by                                                                `gawk '{split($0,n_arr," "); getline; n=split($0,v_arr," "); getline; for (i=2;i<=n;i++)

{
print v_arr[i]}

}' test.dat | sed "s/[^0-9].[^0-9]//g" | tr '\n' "," | sed 's/,$//'`       but this is leaving blank values when a non-numeric value is present. where am I doing a mistake, how to do this from initial awk.

Comment: See if this is what you want: gawk '{split($0,n_arr," "); getline; n=split($0,v_arr," "); getline; for (i=1;i<=n;i++){if (v_arr[i]~/[0-9]+/){l=l v_arr[i] ","} }} END {print substr(l,1,length(l)-1)}'

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '/value/ {
                 if ((getline values) > 0) {
                     split(values, array)
                     for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++)
                         print $i "=" array[i]
                 }
              }' inputfile
```

Instead of `/value/` you might use `/[[:alpha:]]/`

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '
    NF==0 {next}
    var[1] == "" {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) var[i]=$i; next}
    {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {print var[i] "=" $i; delete var[i]}}
'
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
sed '/^$/d;N;:a;s/\([^ \n]*\) *\([^\n]* *\n\) *\([^ \n]*\) *\(.*\)/\2\4\n\1=\3/;/^\n\n/!ba;s///' file
```